# sending volley request with nested hashmap parameters

Tags: android, rest, android-volley

i am using android volley framework  for sending jsonobject request to my server.get request is working fine.now i would like to send a post request with request parameters which is nested hashmap< string,object >.i override the getparams method but it expects me to send hashmap< string,string >.

there is any way to pass hashmap as request parameter?

i have followed this link [enter link description here](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/05/android-working-with-volley-library-1/)

Comment: have u got answer for this?

Answer (score 1):

try override below method, it is from source code:

```
/**
 * Returns the raw POST or PUT body to be sent.
 *
 * @throws AuthFailureError in the event of auth failure
 */
public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
    Map<String, String> params = getParams();
    if (params != null && params.size() > 0) {
        return encodeParameters(params, getParamsEncoding());
    }
    return null;
}
```

**Returns the raw POST or PUT body to be sent.**

so override the `getBody()` with your parameter.

Comment: Please do not put useless answers here. Methods you mentioned has private access from Request class in volley and hope private methods can not be override.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getParamsEncoding in override method getBody().

Here, this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49148031/11479936) will help you.