# Pass the multiple JSON object request to API using StringRequest property of Volley library

Tags: android, android-volley, json

i need to pass the multiple JSON object fields in single request to StringRequest property of Volley library.I mentioned the request body below for better understanding.

```
{
"DeviceInfo": {
    "Os": "Android",
    "Access": "true"
  },
  "FirstName": "test",
  "LastName": "test",
  "USerName": "test"
}
```

This has to be passed to StringRequest method and the response has to be fetched.Please help me to fix this, thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906689/volley-post-method-for-json-object?rq=1

Comment: Hi, am tried the code as per in the shared link but i didn't get the response

Comment: not get the response? you mean the server doesnt receive the request or the request is in a wrong format?

Comment: not get the respone means am getting reposne as 400 and 401 exception whereas i checked in postman tool with the same params the success message is received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

atlast i found the answer am just change the content type format in header like x-www-form-urlencoded format instead of json and the response is fetched successfully thanks for the guys who post their solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to convert jsonObject into string.

```
String data = json.toString();
```

and put it into StringRequest

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, data,
        new Response.Listener<String>(), new Response.ErrorListener());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need override `getParams` of `StringRequest` to send json objects to the server.

```
StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
        URL,
        new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String res) {
            }
        },
        new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            }
        }){
    @Override
    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws com.android.volley.AuthFailureError {
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("FirstName", "test");
        return params;
    }
};

Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(request);
```

If you need nested json object, see this post [sending volley request with nested hashmap parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27561421/sending-volley-request-with-nested-hashmap-parameters)

Comment: Hi, yes without using getParams() method we are not able to post the params am aware of that, actually if i have pass simple request like { "FirstName": "test",
  "LastName": "test",
  "USerName": "test"
} for this i've got the reponse for multiple jsonObject request as i mentioned above in question i didn't get the response.

Comment: That may be because the request format is wrong, the server can not parse it but return a 400. I would consider using WireShark to see what is happening. JsonObjectRequest is more suitable. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25906689/volley-post-method-for-json-object?lq=1 @karuppiah

Answer (score 0):

**It is very simple and useful **

> //Preparing parameters

```
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap();

        params.put("FirstName", "test");
        params.put("LastName", "test");
        params.put("USerName", "test");
           try {        
            JSONObject deviceInfoObject= new JSONObject();
            deviceInfoObject.put("Os", "Android");
            deviceInfoObject.put("Access", "true");

            params.put("DeviceInfo", deviceInfoObject);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject(params);
```

Now use this parameters jsonobject for get response

> Note : -   Mapping data must be take <String, Object> , not use
> <String,String>